# Robocopy prepends drive letter on filepaths even when drive is specified

Tags: windows, command-line, robocopy

`robocopy  /"C:\Users\john smith\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\project\checker\bin\Debug\/" /"C:\Users\john smith\project\Assemblies/" checker.dll`

When I run this through the command line it adds an extra C:\ before the filepaths (e.g. `C:\Users\john smith\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\project\checker\bin\Debug\` becomes `C:\C:\Users\john smith\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\project\checker\bin\Debug\`).

Why?

Comment: looks like `/` is interpreted as drive root (`c:\\`). Those forward slashes seem out of place, what's their intended purpose btw?

Comment: It's supposed to escape the quote marks I had to include since my filepaths have spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The forward slashes were unnecessary - they were indeed screwing up robocopy's path interpreter. However, when building with Visual Studio's macros you have to add an extra trailing backslash to escape the included backslash of a path, otherwise it will escape the quote mark.

So the working command is: 
robocopy "C:\Users\john smith\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\project\checker\bin\Debug\" "C:\Users\john smith\project\Assemblies" checker.dll